# Magento 2 site stops working randomly

Tags: error, magento2.2.3

We have built the website using **Magento 2.2.3**. Our site stuck randomly. I'm getting the following error on the console when the site is stucks. If I reload the page, the page is working.

```
    Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(){return function a(b,c,d){function e(g,h){if(!c[g]){if(!b[g]){var i="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!h&&i)return i(g,!0);if(f)return f(g,!0);var j=new Error("Cannot find module '"+g+"'");throw j.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",j}var k=c[g]={exports:{}};b[g][0].call(k.exports,function(a){var c=b[g][1][a];return e(c?c:a)},k,k.exports,a,b,c,d)}return c[g].exports}for(var f="function"==typeof require&&require,g=0;g<d.length;g++)e(d[g]);return e}({1:[function(a,b,c){function d(a){this.name="RavenConfigError",this.message=a}d.prototype=new Error,d.prototype.constructor=d,b.exports=d},{}],2:[function(a,b,c){var d=a(5),e=function(a,b,c){var e=a[b],f=a;if(b in a){var g="warn"===b?"warning":b;a[b]=function(){var a=[].slice.call(arguments),h=d.safeJoin(a," "),i={level:g,logger:"console",extra:{arguments:a}};
    http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
        at makeError (ea50f7eecd2edcaffa739d8da1769ce2.min.js:16)
        at intakeDefines (ea50f7eecd2edcaffa739d8da1769ce2.min.js:77)
        at ea50f7eecd2edcaffa739d8da1769ce2.min.js:97
```

Comment: Have you tried recompiling after one of these stops?

Comment: Please re run static content deploy.

Comment: Yes, I have run the compile command. But still, I'm getting the error randomly.

Comment: @AmitBera I have re-run the static content deploy, but still, I'm getting the error. Please comment.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but it sounds like a js script name conflict. Either you installed a new module or more specific a script that ends up having the same name as a previous one or you are trying to call an already defined function in your html code. In the second case you have to remove that and let requirejs do the job for you!

Try removing the latest modules installed and recompiling... You should be able to find where the problem is